# css class not being displayed properly in auto scroll div

Tags: css, html

I have an overflow div which is on a jquery modal dialog.

```
                    <div style="overflow: auto; height: 300px; width: 780px;">
                        <fieldset>
                            <br />
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNote" runat="server" CssClass="notetext" Width="740px" Rows="6"
                                TextMode="MultiLine" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
                            <br />
                            &nbsp;
                        </fieldset>
                            <div id="notes">
                                <%
                                    Dim note As New note()
                                    Response.Write(note.shownotes(Val(txtRef.Text)))
                                %>                          
                            </div>    
                    </div>
```

Some of what I put in between the overflow is appearing ok and moves up and down with the scrollbar.

Other text which is within a css class does not move up and down with the scrollbar. It's as if it's not part of the div?

It does work in firefox as intended but not IE (as usual!)

Any ideas?

Anything I put in "p class='triangle-right'> is appearing as if not part of the div, and it's ot scrolling up & down.

```
.triangle-right {
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
    /*margin:1em 0 1.5em;*/
    margin:1.5em 0em 1.5em;
    color:#000000;
    background:#ffffff; /* default background for browsers without gradient support */
    width:730px;
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    line-height:1.4em;  
    /* css3 */
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}

/* creates the larger triangle */
.triangle-right:before {
    content:"\00a0";
    display:block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#aaaaaa;
}

.triangle-right:after {
    content:"\00a0";
    display:block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left:39px; /* controls horizontal position */
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border:21px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Try adjusting those :before and :after selectors. Maybe that will help... Could you post an example HTML file (or a link to one, as that would be easier)? Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hack-fixed this in the past with

```
.overflow-div * {
    position: relative;
}
```

However, the problem is related to the positioning of child elements. Make sure that .triangle-right's parent has a position relative.

I recommend starting from scratch with the styles and making sure the positioning works before adding anything else. Often I've found obscure issues this way.

Comment: Ok, I've added that to my css and hasn't made any defference. I've give the overflow div an id of "overflow-div" and no difference either. Yes .triangle-right has got a position of relative.

Comment: My example used a class name of 'overflow-div', not an id. Also, I was referring to .triangle-right's *parent*.